# Finding the n numbers of same inner tag content inside a single tag

Tags: xml, regex, perl

how to get the inner tag content values of same tag which presented inside a single tag without newline character

```
<BOOK-REF ID="Kyle-ch001-bib036"><AUTHOR-REF><SURNAME>Neinstein</SURNAME>, <GIVEN-NAME>L. S.</GIVEN-NAME></AUTHOR-REF>, <AUTHOR-REF><SURNAME>Gordon</SURNAME>, <GIVEN-NAME>C. G.</GIVEN-NAME></AUTHOR-REF>, <AUTHOR-REF><SURNAME>Katzman</SURNAME>, <GIVEN-NAME>D.</GIVEN-NAME></AUTHOR-REF>, <AUTHOR-REF><SURNAME>Rosen</SURNAME>, <GIVEN-NAME>D.</GIVEN-NAME></AUTHOR-REF>, &#x0026; <AUTHOR-REF><SURNAME>Woods</SURNAME>, <GIVEN-NAME>E.</GIVEN-NAME></AUTHOR-REF> (<YEAR-REF>2007</YEAR-REF>). <BOOK-TITLE-REF>Adolescent health care: A practical guide</BOOK-TITLE-REF> (<EDITION-REF>5th ed.</EDITION-REF>). <PLACE-OF-PUBLICATION-REF>Philadelphia</PLACE-OF-PUBLICATION-REF>: <PUBLISHER-REF>Lippincott Williams and Wilkins</PUBLISHER-REF>.</BOOK-REF>
```

I just want to get the content(name alone) inside thenametag and which presented inside the book ref tag,the surname tag may present n times and i want the content in an array

```
my (@arr2);
while ($str =~ /<BOOK-REF ID="([^"]*)">(?:[^\)]*)<SURNAME>(.*?)<\/SURNAME>.*?<YEAR-REF>(\d+\w+)<\/YEAR-REF>.*?<\/BOOK-REF>/sgi){
    my $id = $1;
    my $sname = $2;
    my $year = $3;
    push (@arr2,[$id,$sname,$year]);
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

With XML::Twig. I added a wrapper `books` around the book ref, in case you have more than one in the file. The code works just the same without it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use YAML;
use XML::Twig;

my @by_name;
XML::Twig->new( twig_handlers => { 'BOOK-REF' => sub { book_ref( @_, \@by_name); } })
         -> parse( \*DATA);

print Dump \@by_name;

sub book_ref
  { my( $t, $bookref, $by_name)= @_;
    foreach my $surname ($bookref->descendants( 'SURNAME'))
      { push @$by_name, { name => $surname->text, id => $bookref->att( 'ID'), year =>  $bookref->field( 'YEAR-REF') }; }
    $t->purge; # if the file can be too big to fit in memory
  }



__DATA__
<books>
<BOOK-REF ID="Kyle-ch001-bib036"><AUTHOR-REF><SURNAME>Neinstein</SURNAME>, <GIVEN-NAME>L. S.</GIVEN-NAME></AUTHOR-REF>, <AUTHOR-REF><SURNAME>Gordon</SURNAME>, <GIVEN-NAME>C. G.</GIVEN-NAME></AUTHOR-REF>, <AUTHOR-REF><SURNAME>Katzman</SURNAME>, <GIVEN-NAME>D.</GIVEN-NAME></AUTHOR-REF>, <AUTHOR-REF><SURNAME>Rosen</SURNAME>, <GIVEN-NAME>D.</GIVEN-NAME></AUTHOR-REF>, &#x0026; <AUTHOR-REF><SURNAME>Woods</SURNAME>, <GIVEN-NAME>E.</GIVEN-NAME></AUTHOR-REF> (<YEAR-REF>2007</YEAR-REF>). <BOOK-TITLE-REF>Adolescent health care: A practical guide</BOOK-TITLE-REF> (<EDITION-REF>5th ed.</EDITION-REF>). <PLACE-OF-PUBLICATION-REF>Philadelphia</PLACE-OF-PUBLICATION-REF>: <PUBLISHER-REF>Lippincott Williams and Wilkins</PUBLISHER-REF>.</BOOK-REF>
</books>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [XML::XSH2](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aXSH2):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Dumper;

use XML::XSH2;
xsh << '    end xsh;';
    open 1.xml ;
    for //SURNAME {
        $y = string(../../YEAR-REF) ;
        $s = string(.) ;
        $i = string(ancestor::BOOK-REF/@ID) ;
        perl { push @arr, [$i, $s, $y] } }
    end xsh;
print Dumper \@XML::XSH2::Map::arr;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use XPath queries to extract the values you are interested in. These three XPath queries should return the values you are looking for:

```
//BOOK-REF/@ID
//BOOK-REF/AUTHOR-REF/SURNAME
//BOOK-REF/YEAR-REF
```

To do the XPath queries, use something like [XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aLibXML). Complete example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $xml = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => q{<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BOOK-REF ID="Kyle-ch001-bib036"><AUTHOR-REF><SURNAME>Neinstein</SURNAME>, <GIVEN-NAME>L. S.</GIVEN-NAME></AUTHOR-REF>, <AUTHOR-REF><SURNAME>Gordon</SURNAME>, <GIVEN-NAME>C. G.</GIVEN-NAME></AUTHOR-REF>, <AUTHOR-REF><SURNAME>Katzman</SURNAME>, <GIVEN-NAME>D.</GIVEN-NAME></AUTHOR-REF>, <AUTHOR-REF><SURNAME>Rosen</SURNAME>, <GIVEN-NAME>D.</GIVEN-NAME></AUTHOR-REF>, &#x0026; <AUTHOR-REF><SURNAME>Woods</SURNAME>, <GIVEN-NAME>E.</GIVEN-NAME></AUTHOR-REF> (<YEAR-REF>2007</YEAR-REF>). <BOOK-TITLE-REF>Adolescent health care: A practical guide</BOOK-TITLE-REF> (<EDITION-REF>5th ed.</EDITION-REF>). <PLACE-OF-PUBLICATION-REF>Philadelphia</PLACE-OF-PUBLICATION-REF>: <PUBLISHER-REF>Lippincott Williams and Wilkins</PUBLISHER-REF>.</BOOK-REF>
});

my $xc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new($xml);

my $id = $xc->find('//BOOK-REF/@ID');
my @snames = map $_->textContent => $xc->findnodes('//BOOK-REF/AUTHOR-REF/SURNAME');
my $year = $xc->find('//BOOK-REF/YEAR-REF');

print "$id\n";
print join(', ' => @snames), "\n";
print "$year\n";

# prints:
# Kyle-ch001-bib036
# Neinstein, Gordon, Katzman, Rosen, Woods
# 2007
```

You could save the results nicely in an array like this:

```
push @some_array, +{
    id     => $id,
    snames => \@snames,
    year   => $year
};
```

If you want to follow your original scheme and duplicate the id and year for every sname, then it's:

```
push @arr2, map [ $id, $_, $year ] => @snames;
```

Another potentially useful way to store them would be in a hash keyed over the id field, so

```
$some_hash{$id} = +{
    id     => $id,
    snames => \@snames,
    year   => $year
};
```